Dungeon manga where the main character finds a card and summons a Valkyrie named Sylphie
The protagonist is monitored by the adventure guild, but one day when he was exploring he found a card and summoned a Valkyrie named Sylphie.

Could this be Mob kara Hajimaru Tansaku Eiyuutan (The Story of an Exploration Hero Who Has Worked His Way up From Common People)?
The main character finds a character-card for a Valkyrie called Sylphy
.
